# Authentification failed while connecting to ActiveDirectory from a remote host

Tags: java, ldap, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I wrote the code on Ubuntu 16 and tried to connect to ActiveDirectory on a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine.
 The user name is : siwar
 The user password is : siwarmp
 The domain name is: squeezer.celtron.com
 The VM host address (Windows server 2012) : 192.168.1.115
 The following code did not work and generated an Authentification:

```
package ldap;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NameNotFoundException;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class LdapMain {
    static DirContext ctx = null;
    static String userLog = "cn=siwar,ou=users,dc=squeezer,dc=celtron,dc=com";
    // static String userLog =
    // "cn=siwar,cn=users,dc=squeezer,dc=celtron,dc=com";
    static String userMP = "siwarmp";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.1.115:389/");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=admin,dc=squeezer,dc=celtron,dc=com");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ldap");
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        getGroup(env, 500);
        getRole(env, "readonly");
        validateLogin(env, userLog, userMP);

    }

    private static SearchControls getSimpleSearchControls() {
        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchControls.setTimeLimit(30000);
        // String[] attrIDs = {"objectGUID"};
        // searchControls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
        return searchControls;
    }

    public static Boolean validateLogin(Hashtable<String, String> env, String userName, String userPassword) {

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

        try {
            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            controls.setCountLimit(1);
            controls.setTimeLimit(5000);

            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            results = ctx.search("ou=users,dc=celtron,dc=com", "(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)",
                    getSimpleSearchControls());

            // results = ctx.search("dc=celtron,dc=com",
            // "(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)", getSimpleSearchControls());
            results = ctx.search(userName, "(objectclass=*)", getSimpleSearchControls());
            System.out.println(results);
            while (results.hasMore()) {

                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
                Attribute dnAttr = attrs.get("cn");
                String dn = (String) dnAttr.get();
                System.out.println(dn);

                Attribute gidAttr = attrs.get("gidNumber");
                String gid = (String) gidAttr.get();
                System.out.println(gid);
                // User Exists, Validate the Password

                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);

                return true;
            }
            return false;

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) { // Invalid Login

            return false;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) { // The base context was not found.

            return false;
        } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("LDAP Query Limit Exceeded, adjust the query to bring back less records", e);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (results != null) {
                    results.close();
                }

                if (ctx != null) {
                    ctx.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { /* Do Nothing */
            }
        }
    }

    public static Boolean getRole(Hashtable<String, String> env, String roleName) {

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

        try {
            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            controls.setCountLimit(1);
            controls.setTimeLimit(5000);

            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            results = ctx.search("cn=readonly,ou=roles,dc=celtron,dc=com", "(objectclass=organizationalRole)",
                    getSimpleSearchControls());

            while (results.hasMore()) {

                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
                Attribute dnAttr = attrs.get("roleOccupant");
                String dn = (String) dnAttr.get();
                System.out.println(dn);
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) { // Invalid Login
            System.out.println("Auth failed");
            return false;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) { // The base context was not found.

            return false;
        } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("LDAP Query Limit Exceeded, adjust the query to bring back less records", e);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (results != null) {
                    results.close();
                }

                if (ctx != null) {
                    ctx.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getGroup(Hashtable<String, String> env, int gid) {

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

        try {
            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            controls.setCountLimit(1);
            controls.setTimeLimit(5000);

            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            results = ctx.search("ou=groups,dc=celtron,dc=com", "(gidNumber=500)", getSimpleSearchControls());

            while (results.hasMore()) {

                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
                Attribute dnAttr = attrs.get("cn");
                String dn = (String) dnAttr.get();
                System.out.println(dn);

                return dn;
            }
            return "";

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {

            return "";
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

            return "";
        } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("LDAP Query Limit Exceeded, adjust the query to bring back less records", e);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (results != null) {
                    results.close();
                }

                if (ctx != null) {
                    ctx.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part is failing and what is the error message?

Comment: Actually, it is working because I fixed some security issues on my windows host.